# Error using xlwings: RunFrozenPython + Arguments

Tags: python, vba, xlwings

I was able to connect Excel and Python thanks to the module xlwings, e.g. I used the following code to call a function from print.py, using one argument, in this case a path to a data file:

```
RunPython ("import print; print.print_vars(r'" & fullpath & "')")
```

Now I built a frozen module out of the Python code and I want to call the frozen version (saved in the same folder \dist\print\print.exe), also with using the argument as shown above.

I tried:

```
RunFrozenPython (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\dist\spss_print\spss_print.exe", "r'" & fullpath & "'")
```

which prompts an error directly in the VBA Module (expecting : =)

as well as:

```
RunFrozenPython (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\dist\print\print.exe r'" & fullpath & "'")
```

which results in an error message when running the macro (The line entered is too long).

I looked already at the Database example from github (https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/tree/v0.3.5/examples/database) but this does not use arguments together with frozen modules. The instruction from https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/deployment.html#runfrozenpython suggests a different code which is not working either.

Can anybody tell me how I need to re-write the call in the VBA module?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ouch, the docs weren't properly updated with the last updates (the [changelog](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/whatsnew.html#v0-15-6-apr-29-2019) mentions it though). Will be fixed with the next release. Use `RunFrozenPython "C:\path\to.exe", "arg1 arg2"`

Comment: Hello Felix,
thanks, with this code, I can run the code and the Python exe script. However, I do not find a way to use the arguments for my python script. I wrote a simple function (nothing happens here when calling just this) and after that I tried also to add a line to run this function with the two arguments, which are not found then... Could you provide any examples how to use arguments when using Frozen modules?
Thanks

Comment: posted a full sample below

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example:

```
import xlwings as xw
import sys


def hello_xlwings(arg1, arg2):
    wb = xw.Book.caller()
    wb.sheets[0].range("A1").value = arg1 + arg2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello_xlwings(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

then after freezing, call it like this from VBA:

```
RunFrozenPython "C:\path\to.exe", "arg1 arg2"
```

Comment: Hello Felix, thanks for this line of code, I did not come across this yet. I'm still getting an error, but I thing this might be caused by Excel/VBA:
In my example I am reading the 2 arguments as numbers (double) from 2 cells and then I am running the Python code which is pretty close to your example (doing some changes with the arguments and then writing it to two cells in the workbook). I am getting the following error:
[1568] Failed to execute script testargs_frozen
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'arg1'
Any ideas on that? It works just fine in the nonfrozen version.

Comment: When you pass in arguments to a command line executable (i.e. your frozen python code), arguments will arrive as strings. So you need to make sure to transform them into numbers by adding `float()` or `int()` around them.

Comment: Yep, did this already as "check" for the data in the non-frozen version, I transformed both args to int()...